# event.charCode to String gives weird characters

Tags: javascript

when I convert event.charCode to a String all the characters except the numbers and the letters give a different String/Char than what it is supposed to output.

Here is my code:

```
alert("Key Pressed: " + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) + "\n"
  + "charCode: " + e.charCode);
```

When I press "/" I get a weird 1/2 symbol which I don't want, this also goes for all the other chars EXCEPT the letters and numbers.
How do I get the correct format for the symbols so that they math a US keyboard?

Comment: What browser are you using? In what event handler is this placed? http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Use `e.which` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.charCode

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome, will try out e.which. Thanks for the answers so far!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `e.which` and the [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keypress) listener, not [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keydown). Keydown will give you weird values because it's listening for every key on the keyboard and it assigns special values to all of them.

You want `keypress`because it looks for text-entry keys (keys that, when pressed, produce a character) rather than actionable keys (like <kbd>enter</kbd> and arrow keys) and is case sensitive. Using `.which` normalizes the value and all keys should work as expected.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/t9Z89/)**

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem. I was using onkeydown, onkeypress fixed it.